# Samples to converge to mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation, means

Consider the set $\{-K,-K+1,\dots,0,1,\dots,K\}$. Consider the random variable $a$ which picks integers from the set uniformly. We expect the mean of $a$ to be $0$.

How many samples we need for the mean to converge to range $[-\delta,\delta]$ with probability $p$?

Comment: With $n$ draws, note that the coefficient of $x^i$ in $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2k}x^i\right)^n$ is the amount of cases where the sum of draws is equal to $i-k n$. The total amount of cases is $(2 k + 1)^n$

Comment: what does this give to this problem?

Comment: What tools can you use? Do you need an exact calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote
$$
a_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k,
$$
where $X_k$'s are iid random variables with the uniform distribution on $\{-K,\ldots,K\}$. Using Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
P(|a_n|>\delta)\le\frac{\operatorname{Var}a_n}{\delta^2}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
P(|a_n|\le\delta)\ge1-\frac{\operatorname{Var}a_n}{\delta^2}.
$$
Since
$$
\operatorname{Var}a_n=\frac1{n^2}\cdot n\cdot \operatorname{Var}X_1=\frac1n\cdot\frac{(2K+1)^2-1}{12},
$$
we have that
$$
P(|a_n|\le\delta)\ge1-\frac1{\delta^2}\cdot\frac1n\cdot\frac{(2K+1)^2-1}{12}.
$$
By choosing $n$ large enough, we can make the right side of the inequality above greater or equal to $p$, which is the desired probability.

This is only a bound, but I hope that this is useful.

Comment: yeah i want more precise reasoning .. for example if $\delta$ is very small your bound says nothing I think.

Comment: @Robut If by nothing you mean that you need a very large $n$, then yes, it says nothing.

Comment: how good is this? can there be more improvement?

Comment: @Robut I’m not sure how good this bound is. I’m not saying that it is good or bad, it’s a simple bound that we can obtain in a few steps. I’d guess that this bound should be ok for large values of $n$ and that a better bound might be obtained using higher order moments. Theoretically, you can calculate the probability that the sample is in the given interval (I mean calculate exactly) and you can obtain an explicit expression of the dependence on $n$ of this probability. But I think the calculation might be very complicated.

Comment: This is an useful bound I just wonder how well the asymptotics can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Your distribution has an expected value of $0$ and a variance of $\dfrac{k(k+1)}{3}$ so the average of $n$ independent samples (with replacement) has an expected value of $0$ and a variance of $\dfrac{k(k+1)}{3n}$

Using a Central Limit Theorem normal approximation, this suggests that something like $n \gt \dfrac{k(k+1) \left(\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)\right)^2}{3\delta^2} $  should be a reasonable estimate except in extreme cases, where $\Phi^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal.

For example, if $k=3$, $p=0.9$ and $\delta=0.1$ then $\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right) \approx 1.64485$ and this suggests you should look at something like $n \gt 1082.2$.  It will not be precise, but will usually be close

Answer (score 0):

You may want to apply the sampling distribution of the mean:

$$X_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k \mbox{ where } X_k \sim a$$

For large $n$ we can approximate $X_n$ by a normal distribution:

$$X_n \stackrel{approx}{\sim} N(\mu_a,\frac{\sigma_a^2}{n})$$

where

$$\mu_a = 0$$

and

$$\sigma_a^2 = \sum_{k=-K}^K k^2\cdot \frac{1}{2K+1}=\frac{2}{2K+1}\sum_{k=1}^K k^2 = \frac{2}{2K+1}\frac{K(K+1)(2K+1)}{6} = \frac{K(K+1)}{3}$$

Now you normalize $X_n$ which gives (approximately) a standard normal distribution $Z$:

$$\frac{X_n\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_a}\stackrel{approx}{\sim}N(0,1)$$

So:

$$P(|X_n| \leq \delta) = P(\frac{|X_n|\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_a} \leq \frac{\delta\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_a}) \approx P(Z \leq \frac{\delta\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_a}) \mbox{ where } Z \sim N(0,1)$$

With $\Phi(z) = P(Z\leq z)$, you get the following equation giving a relation between your interval $[-\delta,\delta]$, the probability $p$ and the sample size $n$:

$$2\Phi(\frac{\delta\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_a}) - 1 = p$$

I hope this helps.